# scrollToLocation function of SectionList not working in React Native for Web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scroll, react-native-web, react-native-sectionlist

I'm trying to use `scrollToLocation` function of `SectionList` component in React Native for scrolling to a specific section.

I implemented and tested simple code using Snack Expo. It's working on mobile devices, but not working in Web. Although I clicked "Scroll" button, nothing happens.

https://snack.expo.dev/ymKKnvk_b?platform=web

Is there any possible way to make this working? Previously, I saw some websites with this features which is supported by React Native. If anyone knew this issue, I wish your help.